# Qt - Adding a drawing to a Layout

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make an application where the user can input some drawings (gestures) that will then be saved and displayed in a gallery on the top of the screen:

[image]

When the user presses "Validate", the drawing is supposed to be displayed on the scroll area on the top. However, for some reason, my code is not working the way I intended it to. It saves the drawing with no problem, but when I tell it to add it to the top, nothing happens.

Code here:

```
void MainWindow::galleryUpdate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gestureTemplates.size(); i++)
    {
        QPolygonF scaledGesture = gestureTemplates[i].scaleToSquare(gestureTemplates[i]);
        StrokeDrawer * strD = new StrokeDrawer();

        QPalette Pal(palette());
        Pal.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::white);
        strD->setMinimumSize(50, 50);
        strD->setAutoFillBackground(true);
        strD->setPalette(Pal);

        galleryList.append(strD);
        topZone->addWidget(strD);
        strD->setStroke(scaledGesture);
    }
}
```

`gestureTemplates` is a vector of `GestureTemplate` (a custom class inheriting from `QPolygonF`) containing all the drawings. The first line inside the `for` simply scales the drawing to fit in a square, and returns a `QPolygonF`.

`StrokeDrawer` is the class used to display the drawing (code below). I then try to fill it with a white background, save it to `galleryList` which is a list of `StrokeDrawer` for each drawing, and then add it to the top, by using `topZone->addWidget(strD)`, where `topZone` is a `HBoxLayout`.
I also use the `setStroke` method to set the drawing to the `StrokeDrawer` (this method also calls the `update()` function in the class, which calls its `paintEvent`, which should take care of actually drawing the `QPolygonF`).

Initially, I tried to do `addWidget` by directly using the `QPolygonF` but that didn't work. That's why I'm using this `StrokeDrawer` class (which just displays the drawing, it doesn't even allow making changes to it).

By debugging the code on QtCreator, everything works fine until the `addWidget` line, where nothing happens. I mean, even if the drawing is not being correctly displayed, it *should* at least show a small, white, 50x50 square, or am I missing something here?

Some code for `StrokeDrawer`:

```
void StrokeDrawer::setStroke(QPolygonF g)
{
    gesture = g;
    update();
}

void StrokeDrawer::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
    QWidget::paintEvent(e);
    QPainter pait(this);

    if (!gesture.empty())
        pait.drawPolyline(gesture);
}
```

Comment: Your drawing should be a separate image, for example a QPixmap object, then you can display that in a widget, and you can even draw from the widget ontop the pixmap and update the widget to show the changes.

Comment: @ddriver I just tried to use a `QPixmap`, and draw the `QPolygonF` in it, but when I used `addWidget` it says there's no matching function for `addWidget(QPixmap*)`, and that it's not possible to convert `QPixmap*` to `QWidget*`

Comment: I just saw I can create a QLabel and set a QPixmap to that, gonna see if it works

Comment: The label will allow you to show a pixmap, but not to draw on it. You will need to implement a custom widget, re-implement the input events and use them to draw on the pixmap.

Comment: It's ok, I don't need to draw on the upper part anyway, just see the drawings that were already made. Finally got it to work too. Was having trouble with the QLabels not appearing in the layout, and then saw that I had a problem with scope (dat attention span). But at least now it works, thanks!